# Is it possible to use wrapper functions in .so library? If not, is there anything that can provide the same functionality?

Tags: c, wrapper, .so

In a binary `foo`, it calls function `pthread_mutex_lock()`. I do not have access to its source code, so I cannot recompile it. But I want to make it use my own implementation of locks.

To use my own locks, I want to create a library `lock.so`, then use `LD_PRELOAD` to replace the original `pthread_mutext_lock` calls. But I need to use `pthread_mutex_lock` in the middle of my implementation of `lock()`. Is there anyway I can use wrapper functions (`-Wl,-wrap=pthread_mutex_lock`) to do that? I believe the `ld` is performed by the linker, is it? So if I cannot use the wrapper function, how can I do it?

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: You may try to call `__pthread_mutex_lock` in your implementation, it's a common use case for hooking. See the code 
here:https://code.woboq.org/userspace/glibc/nptl/pthread_mutex_lock.c.html#612

Comment: What you are asking for is called “interposition.” Searching for that or “interpose” or “interposing” will yield relevant information.